# Использую toast и он почему-то белый. Как решить?

Tags: javascript, jquery, laravel, toast

Фикшу баг на проекте и мой toastr белого цвета (бэкграунд)
Это очень странно, ибо есть 2 страницы одного проекта, но на одной он белый, а на другой как и ожидается голубоватый. Есть предположения из-за чего это происходит?
Код писал не я...впервые имею дело с этой функцией и пока не догоняю что не так
[image: первая страница проекта где ф-ция почему-то белая]

[image: вторая страница проекта где всё работает тип-топ]

Кто понимает где копать возможно надо копать - подскажите пожалуйста

Comment: Удалял сообщение покопался ещё...много перерыл...toast.min.css - стоит голубой цвет
в toast.min.js тоже вроде проблем не обнаружил...но по факту 2 страницы одного проекта и такая извиняюсь за выражение дичь

Comment: так может инспектор объектов включит и мышой в него потыкать, сравнив стили и верстку на обеих страницах?

Comment: Дело в том что я уже перетыкался до ужаса)

Comment: Видимо, придется взять перерыв, отдохнуть, и потыкаться еще

Comment: На одной страницы не подключен css от тоастера.